jenkins performance issues when using langchain directory loader
I am using baremetal-hypervisor proxmox on my local pc.
There's a virtual machine(12 vcpu, 16 gib) on which jenkins is installed and executed.
And as a part of jenkins pipeline, there's a stage which calls python script.
So, I placed the python script in the jenkins' workspace directory, so that jenkins can call python script on every build/deploy stage.
The problem is about the python script which uses langchains directory loader.
from langchain_community.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader
from langchain.chains.combine_documents import create_stuff_documents_chain
import nltk


nltk.download('punkt_tab')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger_eng')

loader = DirectoryLoader('./demo/src', glob="**/*.java", show_progress=True)
print("direcotryLoader Done")

docs = loader.load()
print("loader Done")

As you can see, the directory loader reads application project directory and finds java files.
But, when "loader.load()" is executed on the jenkins pipeline, it takes too much time(7~8 minutes).(When I execute sample3.py manually, the whole task takes only 3~4 seconds.)
I don't know why "loader.load()" takes too much time only when executed on the jenkins pipeline.
I think the virtual machine's cpu/mem is enough.
Also, I've already tried configuring jenkins' heap memory size(at /etc/default/jenkins), but there was no effect.
In my reasonable thought, the time difference between jenkins' excution and manual execution is due to the allocated resource which jenkins can use.
But, I don't know how to configure it, excepts heap memory.
Or is there any other reason?

"I think the virtual machine's cpu/mem is enough" - you don't need to think about it, it's available for observation. Does memory usage go up? Is the CPU maxed out? Any excessive IO?

Thank you. When the "directoryLoader Done" is printed, It took some time(7~8min) before cpu maxed up and the time that cpu maxed up is when 'loader.load()' works. Recently, I replaced the directoryLoader with textLoader and it really had an effect(Before textLoader code, I added some code about searching for the java files in the working directory). But, I can't figure it out why it works..
